# pre-coital fluid

Tags: sex, wudu, husband-wife, ghusl, men

Assalamu alaikum 
Is it necessary to change my clothes if I found pre cotial fluid in it . What if I'm having ejacuation of pre cotial fluid after every time having a conversation with my partner ? Is it necessary to change clothes for salah and prayer if it is uncontrollable and happening more often ?

Comment: At the time of the prophet only a few people had more than one dress. Changing clothes seems rather a luxury issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer from islamqa 
Read it Completely

It must be noted that madhiy is naajis (impure), and any part of the body that it touches must be washed. As for clothing, Islam is lenient about purifying it so as to ward off hardship. It is sufficient for you to take a handful of water and sprinkle it on the place that has been touched by madhiy, because when the Messenger (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) was asked about how to cleanse a garment of madhiy, he said: “It is sufficient for you to take a handful of water and sprinkle your garment where you think the madhiy touched it.” Narrated by al-Tirmidhi (115); classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.